# How can I get all files from all folders?

Tags: c#, copy

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Copy_Files
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<string> foldersToCopyFrom = new List<string>();
        string folderToCopy;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            foldersToCopyFrom = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\tempVideo\Storm.mp4\", "*.*").ToList();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I want to get all the files from all folders inside the folder Storm.mp4 and copy them all to folderToCopy (for example if folderToCopy; = c:\test)

But first foldersToCopyFrom is empty. I tried *.* and *.jpg since the files in the folders are all images. But it's empty.

And then how do I copy them to the folderToCopy ?

Answer (score 0):

So we need to find the files in the first directory, but we also need to handle when we find another directory by getting those files.

You said that you tried [Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8) with .jpg and .png or "*.jpg|*.png", 
the search pattern only works for [one filter](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b0c31115-f6f0-4de5-a62d-d766a855d4d1/directorygetfiles-with-searchpattern-to-get-all-dll-and-exe-files-in-one-call?forum=netfxbcl) eg "*.png"

But we can filter the files easily on our own, which there is many ways we can.
(I used LINQ) to filter the extensions

In C# there is a lot of built in methods to help us with this problem.

In my Example I recursively found all files and instead of using GetFiles I used Enumerate Files,(which the differences are explained in the first linked provided)
then I copied them from the source directory to the target.

**Copy Files Example:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;


static class Files
{
    static void CopyAll(string source, string target, List<string> extensions)
    {

        var sourceInfo = new DirectoryInfo(source);
        var targetInfo = new DirectoryInfo(target);


        if (!sourceInfo.Exists)
            throw new FileNotFoundException($"File \"{sourceInfo.FullName}\" does not exist!");

        CopyAll(sourceInfo, targetInfo, extensions);

    }
    static void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo sourceInfo, DirectoryInfo targetInfo, List<string> extensions)
    {

        Directory.CreateDirectory(targetInfo.FullName); //Creates directory if does not exist.


        //Get Files and Filter our extensions
        List<FileInfo> files = sourceInfo.EnumerateFiles()
                .Where(file => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file.Name).ToLower())).ToList();

        foreach (FileInfo currentFile in files)
        {
            // Make full path to new file 
            string destination = Path.Combine(targetInfo.FullName, currentFile.Name);
            Console.WriteLine($"Copying {currentFile.Name} to {destination}");


            // fileInfo.CopyTo(target,overwrite)
            currentFile.CopyTo(destination, true);
        }

        //Now we handle directories and sub directories.
        foreach (DirectoryInfo SubDirInfo in sourceInfo.EnumerateDirectories())
        {
            //We have to create the source directories  in the the target directory if they do not exist
            DirectoryInfo TargetSubDir = targetInfo.CreateSubdirectory(SubDirInfo.Name);

            //Recursively call  this function to get the files from this sub directory and into the new sub directory
            CopyAll(SubDirInfo, TargetSubDir, extensions);
        }


    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var extensions = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".png" };
        CopyAll("FoldersToCopyFrom", "FolderToCopyTo", extensions);

        Console.Read();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do, get the files inside the `Storm.mp4` folder and its sub-folder, is append to the arguments, in your `Directory.GetFile`, [SearchOption.AllDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.searchoption?view=netframework-4.8).

So you would have:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foldersToCopyFrom = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\tempVideo\Storm.mp4\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
}
```

To copy them to the `folderToCopy`, you would need to use [File.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_Copy_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_), e.g.

```
public void CopyTo(string[] files, string directory, bool overwriteIfExists)
{
    if (files == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("files");
    }
    else if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
    {
        //throw Exception;

        Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
    }
    int length = files.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        File.Copy(files[i], directory, overwriteIfExists);
    }
}
```

So your full code would be something like:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    CopyTo(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\tempVideo\Storm.mp4\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList().ToArray(), @"c:\test", true);
}

public void CopyTo(string[] files, string directory, bool overwriteIfExists)
{
    if (files == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("files");
    }
    else if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
    {
        //throw Exception;

        Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
    }
    int length = files.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        File.Copy(files[i], directory, overwriteIfExists);
    }
}
```

If you will also need to recreate the sub-directories in the folder which you copied the files to, all you would need to do for that is use `Directory.CreateDirectory` along with the provided file name's directory name, with the replaced, `C:\temp\tempVideo\Storm.mp4\`, start:

```
///////////////
//CopyTo method
///////////////

int length = files.Length;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    string file = files[i];

    string name = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        name = name.Replace(@"C:\temp\tempVideo\Storm.mp4\", directory);

        if (!Directory.Exists(name))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(name);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        name = directory;
    }
    File.Copy(file, name, overwriteIfExists);
}
```